# Convert Sybase To Oracle

Tags: oracle, sybase, powerbuilder

We have ERP system created by Powerbuilder and using  Sybase SQL AnyWhere10 database ,some of our customers need Oracle database ,so we decide to convert  SQL AnyWhere10 to Oracle and there are ability in system to using Sybase or Oracle. I need help where do I start ?

Comment: To convert an ERP system from Sybase to Oracle? I'd start by hiring a consultant to map it all out for you and show you how to do it. That is a BIG question even for SO.

Comment: Ditto on answer below, huge project.  Here are a few tips... Oracle has a conversion tool that will go and convert your sybase code to Oracle and I believe it is free.  The downside is that the conversion is far from perfect.  Some big challenges you will have are with triggers, char datatypes in Sybase, and any temp table logic in Sybase.  Triggers are way different and you'll have to wrestle with recursive trigger code, and dealing with converting triggers to row level triggers.

Comment: Could you please tell us the version of Oracle you're migrating to?
We migrated from Sybase ASA 12 to Oracle 10 using [Ispirer SQLWays Tool][1] for automatic migration of both schema and data.
[1]:http://www.ispirer.com/products/sybase-to-oracle-migration?click=7398510&from=so

Answer (score 1):

I helped doing a migration from Sysbase Anywhere to Oracle once. Nearly all scripts (like views, functions, procedures, ...) need to be changed. We used a self-written tool which connected to both servers and copied the scripts verbatim from Anywhere to Oracle server, then I edited the new script so that it was possible to compile it.

It is a lot of work, and more or less impossible to automate.

Answer (score 1):

Having done this before on a non-trivial PowerBuilder project (45 PBLs, ~3000 objects), this is a BIG task.  It took a team of 3-4 developers and a dedicated DBA the better part of a year to convert our project to Oracle and not break things too badly.

You mention running on either SQL Anywhere or Oracle.  The two are very different in ways that will make you crazy trying to provide equivalent function. As @DisplacedGuy mentions, triggers, temp table usage, and datatype differences at a minimum will require attention. I last used Oracle regularly in v8; the way it returns data for embedded SQL is different from Sybase. Depending on the constructs used in your DWOs, you may have to go to dynamic DWs, maintain separate libraries, or add a completely isolating data access layer if you don't already have one.

My suggestion is to hire someone who's done this already to guide you, if you can. Plan time & money for training your folks.

Good luck.